# Website content is not responsive in PDF A4 page

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer for exporting my website with highchart.js graphs to A4 PDF. I have problems with content in PDF.

Let's say my website look like this:
[image]

How my website look when I export it to PDF A4 format size:
[image]

As you can see on pdf, my graphs are not responsive at all. I want to capture my content with 1920x1080 and put it to A4.

If I'm using the scale as a property in PDF then PDF export looks good.

```
return await page.pdf({
    path,
    printBackground: true,
    landscape,
    format: 'A4',
    scale: await calculcateScale(landscape, rect.width, rect.height) //rect is x,y, width, height of my div
});
```

I don't want to use a scale because I need my graphs to be on multiple pages.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Other puppeteer code:**

1. I set viewport as: `defaultViewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080, deviceScaleFactor: 2}`
2. navigate to my page ...
3. wait for specific div with my graphs `await page.waitForSelector("#graphs");`
4. page pdf

```
return await page.pdf({
    path,
    printBackground: true,
    landscape,
    format: 'A4',
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `pdf` function behaves like a print action. That means [@media print](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) applies.

So you "responsive" style for PDF should be under:

```css
@media print {

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't really help me with my problem. I used scale and I need to readjust my other code for that.